# Is it possible to add two CheckedListBox.DisplayMember?

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I want to display two columns from my List

My code:

```
BindingSource DatenNameVorfahr = new BindingSource();
BindingSource DatenNameNachfolg = new BindingSource();
DataClasses1DataContext d = new DataClasses1DataContext();

////

var query = from pers in d.Person select pers;

List<Person> personen = query.ToList();

DatenNameVorfahr.DataSource = query;
DatenNameNachfolg.DataSource = query;

clNachfolg.DataSource = DatenNameVorfahr;
clVorfahr.DataSource = DatenNameNachfolg;

clNachfolg.DisplayMember = "Name" + "Nachname"; <----! (doesnt work) 
clNachfolg.ValueMember = "ID";
```

When I do this my CheckedListBox only displayes the "ID" (its the first column in my database / list)

Comment: The `DisplayMember` property can only bind to one column. For 2 properties you might create a second `CheckedListBox` and sync them with each other.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. The DisplayMember and ValueMember can only be binded to a single property / column. What you can do is create another class that will inherit `Person` and have a `FullName` property and bind to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would simply be to use a bit of LINQ to get a new List with the Name and Nachname concatenated and bind to that instead.  Something like:

```
var query2 = from q in query
                select new
                {
                    FullName = q.Name + " " + q.Nachname,
                    Id = q.Id
                };
DatenNameNachfolg.DataSource = query2;
clNachfolg.DataSource = DatenNameNachfolg;
clNachfolg.DisplayMember = "FullName";
clNachfolg.ValueMember = "Id";
```

HTH

Comment: Now my CheckedListBox looks good, but people with only a "Name" and without a "Nachname" / Surname are completely empty...

Comment: Can you debug your original query and check that it contains entries with no Nachname?

Comment: Its my database so i know my query has entries without "Nachname".

Comment: That wasn't my question.  Are you seeing them in "query"?

Comment: So in query i can see them... but in query2 the Fullname is null, look like this:  "FullName = null"

Comment: Try `FullName = q.Name + (q.Nachname == null ? "" : " " + q.Nachname),`

Comment: Maybe you can try `FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", q.Name, q.Nachname)` the string.Format should handle the null values, but you still will have an additional space if one between Name or Nachname is null.. you could add a .Trim() after the call to remove spaces, if it is acceptable

Comment: Its works but now the Nachname and Name "sticks" together so, i've added the "space" between "" but it still sticks together

Comment: Sorry - I spotted that error and I edited my comment.  Please look at my comment again